# Third-party custom loggers for MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

Are there any interesting custom loggers for MSBuild already written? I am especially interested in loggers that would record system load (CPU/Memory/IO) data during the build and relate that to actions performed by the build.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [the MSBuild Extension pack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack). This contains a lot of extra custom tasks and loggers.

I don't know about your specific needs for the logger. Remember that the purpose of the logger is only to report on different steps of the build. It only accepts a message and an importance property. You would need to add system load collection by yourself. But again, I don't think this kind of code would belong in a custom logger.